# Can I export the list of Anchor points from Google's [arcore] to excel, for example?

Tags: augmented-reality, virtual-reality, arkit, 3d-model, arcore

Is it possible to use ARCore or ARKit to scan the environment for a list of anchor points and their coordinate, so that you can create a 3D model of the environment from these points?